# How do I get into a Docker container, start a vpn and use my webbrowser just like a VM

Tags: docker, containers

I am wondering if I can replace my virtual machine.
I usually use a Windows VM to get in, connect to my enterprise VPN and do some work.
If the containers are light I like move to, from my MV
Basically I see using containers like processes but not like interactive logon to get into it.

Is this possible?
Regards,

Comment: Running desktop applications like a browser is possible with [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker). VPN setup should be possible, too, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, stick with your VM.  Complicated network setups ("launch a VPN within my container's network space") and desktop applications ("use my Web browser") are both bad matches for Docker, plus running any Docker command requires administrative access on the host, which you probably don't want just to access intranet content.